# Python/Codeacademy : Class average calculation

Tags: python

In one of the exercises, I have to calculate class average. But I facing some issues here..
for calculating class average, I have to iterate over each student which are being passed.
My get_class_average() function is not working as expected.Even though I am calling this function with two student name (alice,lloyd), only the alice is getting processed and my answer is coming 91.15, instead of 85.85...

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

# Add your function below!
def average(numbers):
    total=sum(numbers)
    total= float(total)
    result = total/len(numbers)
    return result

def get_average(student):
    homework = 0.10 * average(student['homework'])
    quizzes = 0.30 * average(student['quizzes'])
    tests = 0.60 * average(student['tests'])

    return (homework + quizzes +tests)


# This section is not working properly     
def get_class_average(students):
    results =[]
    for item in students: <-- This loop may not be working
        print item
        result =get_average(item)
        results.append(result)
        print results
        return average(results)


print get_class_average([alice,lloyd])
```

Comment: A function method can only have one `return`. Your `get_class_average` method has a return statement at the end of the for loop. You should store the average of each one in a temporary list, and then return it.

Comment: iluengo: It is not true. Functions can have more than one `return` statemets. It's just this particular code that causes the error.

Comment: Well yep true, I was talking in this particular case, not in general programming. Btw, thx for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've indented the line

`return average(results)`

to be part of the loop. Since `return` interrupts loops (including `for` loops), only the first iteration of your loop (i.e. with Alice) is running. Try putting this line on the same level as the `for` loop. That way, the loop will complete and AFTER THAT your function will return its result.

Answer (score -1):

Your argument is not defined but you set a loop for each item in students but students are not defined and then you face the problem with your code.

try do something like this:

```
students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

def get_class_average(students):
results = []
 for student in students:
   results.append(get_average(student))
 return average(results)

print get_class_average(students)
```

Here I defined which students I wanna calculate the average with a variable students and then using already one of your functions i just added the result to our list in our variable "results".

Comment: If you scroll down to the last line of the question, you can see where students come from.